# Easy way to parse syslog date format

Tags: bash, sed, awk, perl, syslog

I'd like to write a script that analyses the last week's syslog.

But my syslog logs in a stupid date format, e.g. "May 22". If it logged as 2013-05-22, this task would be trivial.

Is there a way using awk / bash / perl / sed that I can easily 'grep' the logs for all lines between two datetimes?

Comment: what version of syslog are we talking about? Most daemons will let you configure the date format using some kind of directive. You don't have to accept the defaults. It's set up that way by default because some log parsers/analyzers break if you change the date format.

Comment: for example in rsyslog and syslog-ng, you specify the date format in the template you've selected to be default.

Comment: @JoelDavis "some log parsers.. break" exactly why I daredn't change it! Thanks for the tip, will check the man pages for whatever I'm using...

Comment: I'm using syslogd - can't find how to set date format!

Comment: `syslogd` is a bit ambiguous (some syslog variations share that name for their main executable). Is this Mac OS X's `syslogd`?

Comment: Is this Mac OS X's `syslogd`? I'm seeing online that it's based on FreeBSD's syslog, in which case, the [date format is hardcoded](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2009-July/202979.html) it looks like. You may try [changing the daemon to syslog-ng](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040710171559860) if that's more convenient than finding an awk statement that extracts what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit too roundabout for my taste, but it may be of interest to you:

```
perl -p -e '
BEGIN{ 
        @months=qw(jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec);
        $month_number{$_}=++$i for @months;
        $months_regex= join "|",@months;
     }
s/^\s*($months_regex)[a-z]*\s+/$month_number{lc $1}-/i'
/var/log/syslog
```

This will print (to stdout) the log lines with the date in MM-DD format (without zero padding for month numbers) which you seem to be comfortable parsing. This handles month names given in full and month names given in 3-letter form, irrespective of case.

---

**EDIT**

If you want zero padding for month numbers, simply replace `++$i` with `sprintf "%02d",++$i`

**EDIT 2**
Two mistakes fixed thanks to **l0b0**'s comments below:

- Added 'may' to the months list
- Changed the recipe for zero padding to `sprintf "%02d", ++$i`

Answer (score 2):

Would this be OK?

Every line holding date > 10th and < 18th:

```
awk '$2 > 10 && $2 < 18 {print}' file
```

Including month name:

```
awk '$1 == "May" && $2 > 10 && $2 < 18 {print}' file
```

Span months, April 27th to May 4th:

```
awk '($1 == "Apr" && $2 > 26) || ($1 == "May" && $2 < 5){print}' file
```

---

*Update:*

A sketchy variant using getline:

```
awk '"date '+%m%d' -d " $1$2 | getline date; close("date"); \
date > 426 && date < 505 {print}' file
```

Using script:

```
awk -v from=520 -v to=523 '
{
    d = ((match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", $1) + 2) / 3 )$2;
    if (d >= from && d <= to)
        print;

}
' file
```

Using switch:

```
awk -v from=520 -v to=523 '
function date2time()
{
    switch ($1) {
    case "Jan": return 1$2; break;
    case "Feb": return 2$2; break;
    case "Mar": return 3$2; break;
    case "Apr": return 4$2; break;
    case "May": return 5$2; break;
    case "Jun": return 6$2; break;
    case "Jul": return 7$2; break;
    case "Aug": return 8$2; break;
    case "Sep": return 9$2; break;
    case "Oct": return 10$2; break;
    case "Nov": return 11$2; break;
    case "Dec": return 12$2; break;
    }
}
{
    d = date2time();
    if (d >= from && d <= to)
        print;

}
' file
```

Using array:

```
... oh see you have gotten your answer ;)
```

Comment: what about periods which span months?

Comment: Thanks, but it's still difficult to generalise this for a given span. Would have to choose one of 2nd or 3rd forms based on whether the month was different.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it in Perl, although I prefer some of the other answers!

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%B %d %Y');
m/^(\w+ \d+)/;
print $parser->parse_datetime("$1 " . DateTime->now->year)->ymd;
```

Comment: [One-liner](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/b693367007d0f2cc67bf15b8dbc0ed8a08dd6742#.bash_history) replacing the date: `sudo perl -n -e 'use DateTime::Format::Strptime; my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%B %d %Y"); m/^(\w+ \d+ )(.*)/; print ($parser->parse_datetime("$1" . DateTime->now->year)->ymd, " ", $2, "\n");' /var/log/syslog`

Comment: @l0b0 Handy :-P